# MaxScale DB Custom Modules

Tags: mysql, proxy, database-performance

I'm hoping that this may just be a case of me not being able to use Google correctly. I'm wanting to do something very specific using MaxScale where I intercept all of the queries going to my database, run explain plan on those queries first, and then reject the queries outright if the explain plan falls beyond a certain complexity threshold. I'm happy to learn how to write in whatever language is required (C, I think). But I can't seem to find any kind of API docs or examples based on my internet digging.

Here's my configuration file (no idea if it will even help). I'd love to post something I've already tried - but I don't even know what to try!

```
[maxscale]
threads=4

[MySQL Monitor]
type=monitor
module=mysqlmon
servers=master,slave1
user=dbuser
passwd=dbpswd
monitor_interval=10000

[qla]
type=filter
module=qlafilter
options=/tmp/QueryLog

[fetch]
type=filter
module=regexfilter
match=fetch
replace=select

[RW]
type=service
localhost_match_wildcard_host=1
router=readwritesplit
servers=master,slave1
user=dbuser
passwd=dbpswd
max_slave_connections=100%
router_options=slave_selection_criteria=LEAST_CURRENT_OPERATIONS

[RR]
type=service
localhost_match_wildcard_host=1
router=readconnroute
router_options=synced
servers=slave1
user=dbuser
passwd=dbpswd

[Debug Interface]
type=service
router=debugcli

[CLI]
type=service
router=cli

[RWlistener]
type=listener
service=RW
protocol=MySQLClient
address=127.0.0.1
port=3307

[RRlistener]
type=listener
service=RR
protocol=MySQLClient
address=127.0.0.2
port=3307

[Debug Listener]
type=listener
service=Debug Interface
protocol=telnetd
address=127.0.0.2
port=4442

[CLI Listener]
type=listener
service=CLI
protocol=maxscaled
address=127.0.0.2
port=6603

[master]
type=server
address=master.dns.address
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend

[slave1]
type=server
address=slave1.dns.address
port=3306
protocol=MySQLBackend
```

Comment: Is your rationale that `explain` will yield some sort of quick-analysis on how the query will perform, thus it will allow you to determine what's going to be quick and what won't? If the answer is yes then that rationale is false and such scenario won't happen.

Comment: @N.B. You bring up a good point. Mostly I want to protect our DB from ridiculously awful queries with a ridiculous number of joins, we've got a super-power database and still have queries running for 30+ minutes. I want to stop those from happening.

Comment: As much as that sounds great and possibly useful, you've got a terribly complex task at hand - you have to determine what's complex and what isn't and so on. I won't try to butt in and tell you how to do your job or how to think about your idea/system that you have to manage, I'm sure there's a good reason for it but I know 100% that I would not like to be doing that, which usually (in my world) forces me to rethink the logic of the whole system architecture (which, as I mentioned, probably isn't feasible for you at this point) - which means - I wish you the best of luck resolving this :)

Comment: @N.B. Yeah, we have some of that going on too. We're using powerful performance monitoring tools to tell us where the worst offenders are, and refactoring them as we find them. However, right now we're stuck with code being checked in that deviates substantially from best practices, etc. I want to eventually incorporate performance validation into our CI environment, but I'm not sure how easily I can make that operational change either. Thanks for the encouragement!